# In mapview, can I associate symbols other than circles to the data?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-mapview

The default symbol when plotting any latitude-longitude data in mapview is a circle.  What if I'd like to associate a square or "x" to the points on the map?  Is there a way to use different symbols?

Alternatively, can another package get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet package seems to provide a general solution to using [customized icons](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html).  Leaflet uses the term "marker".